# Accessing category method in original Objective C class

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

I have a class for which I have created a *category*. Now I want to access *category method* inside original class but I am getting error:

> error: instance method '-hasSound' not found (return type
>   defaults to 'id') [-Werror,-Wobjc-method-access]

```
// Animal.h 
@interface Animal: NSObject 
- (void)sound;
@end

// Animal.m
#import "Animal+Additions.h"
@implementation Animal
- (void)sound {
 [self hasSound];
}
@end

// Animal+Additions.h
@interface Animal (Additions) 
- (BOOL)hasSound;
@end

// Animal+Additions.h
@implementation Animal (Additions)
- (BOOL) hasSound {
   return YES;
}
@end
```

I have been doing same thing in **Swift** but not sure how to achieve the same thing in **Objective C**. 
Category and original class are in separate files. I have imported Category interface file inside original class but that didn't work.

Comment: Maybe try adding a *forward declaration* in `Animal+Additions.h` (i.e., `@class Animal;`) before the category declaration.

Comment: It still didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not shown sufficient `#import` statements, so I have to assume they don't exist. You need them.

Another possible issue is that, at least according to your comments, you seem to have two *Animal+Additions.h* files but no *Animal+Additions.m* file.

This *complete* code in four files compiles for me:

```
//  Animal.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Animal: NSObject
- (void)sound;
@end

//  Animal.m

#import "Animal.h"
#import "Animal+Additions.h"
@implementation Animal
- (void)sound {
    [self hasSound];
}
@end

// Animal+Additions.h

#import "Animal.h"
@interface Animal (Additions)
- (BOOL)hasSound;
@end

//  Animal+Additions.m

#import "Animal+Additions.h"
@implementation Animal (Additions)
- (BOOL) hasSound {
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Note all the `#import` statements, and note that the *Animal.m* file must be part of the target.